# How do I check multiple element within the list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to check all the element in the list in order to output the final status whether it is true or false. If false the status in UI will display `FAILED` else is `DONE`

Model

```
public class CheckingListModel
{
    public int Overview = 0;
    public int Summary = 0;
    public int Variance = 0;
}
```

Function

```
public bool result()
{
    CheckingListModel checkList = new CheckingListModel();
    bool overviewRequried = true;
    if (overviewRequried)
    {
        try
        {
            //Run Function 
            checkList.Overview = 1; // When Success
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            checkList.Overview = -1; // When Fail
        }
}
if(checkList) //If all check list element is equals to 1 will return true
{
    return true;
}
retrun false;
}
```

The `CheckingListModel` will only be assign value at the Function, 0 is stand for empty. 1 is for true and false is -1.

Comment: Your question is incorrect as you don't have a list. List is spessial collection class in dotnet. You ave fields of an object.

Comment: It's not so good design to encode false as -1 and so on, You could create custom enum for your purpose, or use nullable-bool like `bool?` take a note at `?` sign. This would allow 3 values: null,true,false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method in your checklist could do this for you, it would look really similar to the generated code that visual studio would make if you told it to generate a "equals" override.

```
public class CheckingListModel
{
    public int Overview = 0;
    public int Summary = 0;
    public int Variance = 0;

    public bool IsDone(){
        if(Overview == 1 &&
           Summary == 1 &&
           Variance == 1)
             return true;
        else
             return false;
    }
}
```

then your if statement would look like this:

```
if(checkList.IsDone()) //If all check list element is equals to 1 will return true
{
    return true;
}
retrun false;
}
```

But like mentioned in the comments above by Bogdan Mart using an int to store 3 possible states isn't necessary, a bool? or Nullable would work great also.